# Nested descriptors for acces nested instance values

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-descriptors

How do you write descriptors that return objects having descriptors that return other objects with descriptors? In the code below, `getattr` in `__get__` and `__set__` is called with different instances as parameter, but it references to the same objects. Please advise how to make it pass the attached test.

In general this is supposed to be a helper for generating JSON reports of strict schema. It generates the structure but the values are common across the structure nodes. The problem exposes only when I have several class attributes of same type (ObjectField) in one class.

```
class Uninitialized:
    pass


class FieldDescriptor(object):

    def __init__(self, value_type, json_key, initial_value=Uninitialized):
        self._value_type = value_type
        self._storage_key = json_key
        self._initial_value = initial_value
        self._parent_attr_name = None

    def _check_py_value(self, new_value):
        if new_value is not None and not isinstance(new_value, self._value_type):
            raise TypeError("Bad type %s" % type(new_value).__name__)

    def _form_json_value(self, parent_instance):
        return self.__get__(parent_instance)

    def __get__(self, parent_instance, _=None):
        value = getattr(parent_instance, self._parent_attr_name).val
        return None if value is Uninitialized else value

    def __set__(self, parent_instance, value):
        getattr(parent_instance, self._parent_attr_name).val = value


class StrField(FieldDescriptor):
    def __init__(self, json_key, initial_value=Uninitialized):
        super(StrField, self).__init__(str, json_key, initial_value)


class ListField(FieldDescriptor):
    def __init__(self, json_key, initial_value=Uninitialized):
        super(ListField, self).__init__(list, json_key, initial_value)


class Wrap(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val


class ObjectField(FieldDescriptor):
    def __init__(self, json_key):
        for name_, descriptor in self.iterate_descriptors():
            attr_name = "_value_of_{}".format(name_)  # kind of proxy
            descriptor._parent_attr_name = attr_name
            new_field = Wrap(descriptor._initial_value)
            setattr(self, attr_name, new_field)

        FieldDescriptor.__init__(self, value_type=self.__class__, json_key=json_key, initial_value=self)

    @classmethod
    def iterate_descriptors(cls):
        for attr_name, descriptor in cls.__dict__.iteritems():
            if isinstance(descriptor, FieldDescriptor):
                yield attr_name, descriptor

    def _form_json_value(self, _=None):
        return {dsc._storage_key: dsc._form_json_value(self) for _, dsc in self.iterate_descriptors()}


def test_it_with_pytest():

    class ObjF(ObjectField):
        txt = StrField("OBJF.StrDO")
        list = ListField("OBJF.C")

    class Nest(ObjectField):
        b1 = ObjF("NEST.B1")
        b2 = ObjF("NEST.B2")

    class Root(ObjectField):
        oo1 = Nest('oo1')
        oo2 = Nest('oo2')

    root = Root(None)
    # assign some values
    root.oo1.b1.txt = "DIFFERENT"
    root.oo2.b2.list = [12, 3, 5]

    assert root.oo1._value_of_b1 != root.oo2._value_of_b1  # that pass

    a = root.oo1.b1.txt
    b = root.oo1.b2.txt
    c = root.oo2.b1.txt
    assert a != b  # that pass
    assert a != c  # that fails, 'DIFFERENT' == 'DIFFERENT'

    assert root._form_json_value() == {
        'oo1': {
            'NEST.B1': {
                'OBJF.C': None,
                'OBJF.StrDO': 'DIFFERENT'  # ok
            },
            'NEST.B2': {
                'OBJF.C': None,  # that fails, is [12, 3, 5]
                'OBJF.StrDO': None
            }
        },
        'oo2': {
            'NEST.B1': {
                'OBJF.C': None,
                'OBJF.StrDO': None  # that fails is "DIFFERENT"
            },
            'NEST.B2': {
                'OBJF.C': [12, 3, 5],  # ok
                'OBJF.StrDO': None
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assigning `_parent_attr_name` is something that really ought to be happening in a metaclass `__init__`.

Comment: Yes it was like that before, but since the effect is the same without using metaclasses (I believe), it's ok.

Comment: It does work, and it's simpler for presentation, but the repeated assignments would confuse me in real code.

Comment: "How do you write descriptors that return other descriptors that return other descriptors?" - that's not how descriptors work. If you have a descriptor that returns a descriptor from `__get__`, no attribute access will invoke the returned descriptor's `__get__`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
# for ...
        new_field = Wrap(descriptor._initial_value)
        setattr(self, attr_name, new_field)

FieldDescriptor.__init__(self, value_type=self.__class__, json_key=json_key, initial_value=self)
```

Together, this makes *all* instances of the owning class store the *one* descriptor object under `attr_name`.  Thus `root.oo1.b1 is root.oo2.b1` in your test.  (Similarly, `root.oo1 is Outer(None).oo1`.)

You need to construct new objects for each `ObjectField` attribute; it may be less confusing for these objects to not *be* descriptors themselves (even if they are of a type that has more descriptors for the nested attributes).  Of course, if you're going to preconstruct them you might as well make all the outer objects be normal objects with attributes and no descriptors, leaving the descriptors to check the data types at the leaves.

Alternatively, you can react to the `Uninitialized` value in `__get__` by constructing and installing a new value (when appropriate to the type).

Comment: Thank you Davis. You were absolutely right about the root cause. Although I read your advice several times I couldn't get any solution till now. As you said: `ObjectField` is no longer a descriptor, is derived from `object`. In its `__init__` while iterating `sub-ObjectFields` (which are `class attributes`) i recreate exactly the same classes but as instance attributes (under the same attribute name as class'). `_form_json_value` had to be changed, but it works. thank you very much.